# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] with |

Tags: php, query-string

I'm using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` in my PHP script. My query string of `?e+e` works fine, but `?e|e` does not.

My PHP script is simply:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
?>
```

Why doesn't `|` work?  I seem to be able to use `|` if I don't use use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work". What outcome did you expect? What do you need it for? Is the `QUERY_STRING` truncated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the `|` symbol to `%7C`. then it will work. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will automatically decode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually adding the pipeline symbol in your browser then this might happen

try doing it like this : ?e%7Ce

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct QUERY_STRING cause "|" is not allowed symbol. [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) 2.3.

```
Data must be escaped if it does not have a representation using an
unreserved character; this includes data that does not correspond to
a printable character of the US-ASCII coded character set, or that
corresponds to any US-ASCII character that is disallowed, as
explained below.
```